# Nested json query in Amazon Athena: "Expression data is not of type ROW"

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I need to unnest these json values:

`` CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `cei`( `data` array<struct<data:int,field:string>> COMMENT 'from deserializer',  `field` string COMMENT 'from deserializer') ``

I need the data.data and data.field values, however AWS Athena keep saying 'Expression data is not of type ROW'

here's my query -

```
data.data, data.field
from cei, UNNEST(data.data) t(data), UNNEST(data.field) t(field)
```